# Is it Dragon Ball Super: Super Hero set after or before the Dragon Ball Super Granola saga?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super, dragon-ball-movies

A new *Dragon Ball Super* movie has been released in Japan, and certain events makes it interesting to know when it happens.

Is it *Dragon Ball Super: Super Hero* set after or before the *Dragon Ball Super Granola* saga?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before. There was a tweet showing the moments from Piccolo showing some key moments from his perspective, until the Galactic Patrol.

https://twitter.com/DBSChronicles/status/1519433239236313088/photo/1